# How can i make GUI in ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i make GUI in ros?
like c# or mfc
just custom rqt??
i want make a sliderbar and image processing result window

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228187/how-can-i-make-gui-in-ros?/) by [Master.L](https://answers.ros.org/users/26148/master.l/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2016-03-04**:
Do you really need your own GUI? You can change configuration with trackbars with [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) and show results with rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use rqt - a few links here:

http://wiki.ros.org/rqt

http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_gui

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-03-04**:
You can also create your own rqt plugin : http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin

**Comment by [Master.L](https://answers.ros.org/users/26148/master.l/) on 2016-03-08**:
i'm follow the tutorial but i have many error i don't know why
if use python then make plugin.xml, setup.py .ui file right?

where i can  find the example?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-08**:
Not sure what you mean - there is a python and C++ example here: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials